# Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"private\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Product\"

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, postman

---

Hola, estoy realizando un API Rest con Nodejs y MongoDB y tengo el siguiente problema:

```
{
"message": "Error al realizar la petición: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"private\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Product\""}
```

No entiendo qué me quiere decir eso, para contextualizar agrego algunas partes del código que llevo:

```
'use strict'

const Product = require('../models/product')

function getProduct (req, res) {
    let productId = req.params.productId

    Product.findById(productId, (err, product) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({message: `Error al realizar la petición: ${err}`})
        if (!product) return res.status(404).send({message: `El producto no existe`})

        res.status(200).send({ product })
    })
}

function getProducts (req, res) {
    Product.find({}, (err, products) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({message: `Error al realizar la petición: ${err}`})
    if (!products) return res.status(404).send({message: 'No existen        productos'})

        res.send(200, { products })             
    })
}
```

---

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express')
const productCtrl = require('../controllers/product')
const auth = require('../middlewares/auth')
const api = express.Router()


api.get('/product', productCtrl.getProducts)
api.get('/product/:productId', productCtrl.getProduct)
api.post('/product', productCtrl.saveProduct)
api.put('/product/:productId', productCtrl.updateProduct)
api.delete('/product/:productId', productCtrl.deleteProduct)
api.get('/private', auth, (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send({ message: 'Tienes acceso' })
})

module.exports = api
```

---

```
'use strict'

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const ProductSchema = Schema({
    name: String,
    picture: String,
    price: {type: Number, default: 0 },
    category: { type: String, enum: ['computers', 'phones', 'accesories']},
    description: String
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema)
```

---

Se provoca un error cuando hago un GET para el path `http://localhost:3001/api/product/private/`

Soy nuevo en esto y me siento atascado en este punto, agradezco cualquier aporte. Saludos.

Comment: Pon el codigo en texto, las imagenes son ayuda visual, pero el xodigo facilita la edicion y detecccion de errores.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB utiliza un tipo de id para los documentos llamado ObjectId. Un ObjectId tiene un formato propio, un ejemplo de ObjectId: "507f1f77bcf86cd799439011".

Siguiendo tu modelo, cuando insertas productos, para cada uno se genera un id diferente con el formato de ObjectId.

Cuando tú llamas a http://localhost:3001/api/product/private/, lo que sucede por dentro es que va al findById diciéndole que el id es "private", y cuando intenta convertirlo a ObjectId falla porque no es un ObjectId válido. Y es el error que te está devolviendo "CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"private\""